# How can you determine E(XY) if X is a continuous random variable with a normal distribution and Y is a value that depends on x?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random-variable, covariance, joint-distribution

I have a problem where I need to determine the Covariance of two variables X and Y. I want to do this by the following formula:

Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)

I know the formulas to calculate both E(X) and E(Y) however I am not sure how to determine E(XY).

Y is a continuous random variable that has a normal distribution. X is a variable that is equal to a constant (c) if y<0 and 0 otherwise. So for instance, if y turns out to be equal to 2 this concludes in x = 0. If y = -3, x = c.

When determining the Covariance of the two variables I first thought that it would be 0 since the Covariance of a variable and and a constant is 0. However, since x is dependent on y and since x can be two different numbers, I am not too sure anymore. And if the covariance is not equal to 0, I do not know how to compute E(XY). By doing some research I understood that this needs to be calculated by using the joint probability density function, however how do you determine that function?

To summarise, I am quite lost on this topic so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can try with the law of total expectation which gives $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E(XY \mid Y)\right] =\mathbb E\left[Y \mathbb E(X \mid Y) \right]$. Then $ \mathbb E(X \mid Y)$ can be computed from the definition of $X$ and you'll then have to compute an expectation that only depends on $Y$.

Comment: $E[XY] = E[E[XY|Y]] = E[Y E[X|Y]] = E[Y c \mathbb{I}(Y < 0)] = c E[Y \mathbb{I}(Y < 0)]$. Now, you need the density of $Y \mathbb{I}(Y < 0)$ and its expectation, which should be derived following the derivations for the half-normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

Comment: @joy thank you for your response! I understand everything you do, expect for the last explanation where you mention the half-normal distribution. Could you explain maybe a bit more in detail why this needs to be used? Maybe it is also important to mention that it is not a standard normal distributed variable.

Comment: If $Y \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, then then the distribution of $|Y|$ is half-normal with parameter $\sigma$. The explicit expression of its mean is known. However, even in this case, the distribution of $Y\mathbb{I}(Y < 0)$ is not half-normal. However, the derivation of the expectation of $Y\mathbb{I}(Y < 0)$ should be similar to that of the half-normal distribution. For general normal distribution, the distribution of distribution of $Y\mathbb{I}(Y < 0)$ is of-course not half-normal, and I don't know if its expectation at all has an explicit expression.